# dfR = spark.read.format("csv").option("mode", "FAILFAST").option("header","true").schema(sch).load(fileName) ---- Not working

Tags: azure, csv, pyspark, azure-synapse, read.csv

My FAILFAST option to read the csv is not working for the ill-formed record in the middle of the csv file. The file is supposed to have 7 columns separated by ','. I have mocked my csv file to have an additional 8th column in one of records in the middle and made another record with 6 columns. code is below:

schema:

```py
sch = StructType(
    [
        StructField("SecurityDescription", StringType(), True),
        StructField("RIC", StringType(), False),
        StructField("UniversalClosePrice", DecimalType(18, 9), False),
        StructField("UniversalClosePriceDate", DateType(), False),
        StructField("FXIRScalingFactor", StringType(), False),
        StructField("FileCode", StringType(), False),
        StructField("BaseCurrencyCode", StringType(), True),
    ]
)


dfR = (
    spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
    .option("header", "true")
    .schema(sch)
    .load(fileName)
)
```

After searching the net I even tried by adding .cache() at the end but still it passes the ill-formed record file as valid file. My expectation is that the job should abort.

Tried:

```py
dfR = (
    spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
    .option("header", "true")
    .schema(sch)
    .load(fileName)
)

# -- ALSO --
dfR = (
    spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
    .option("header", "true")
    .schema(sch)
    .load(fileName)
    .cache()
)
```

Expectations:
Job should abort with exception when encountering ill-formed record file.

Comment: please add a sample input file

Comment: Please ignore the question. I figured out that the error will happen when you try to access the Dataframe of the bad csv file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**@Wasim Syed** Nice to know, your problem is resolved. Making it an answer, will use full to other community members who have a similar issue.

**Note:** The schema you provided has seven fields, but your CSV file contains only eight record fields and another with six records. That is the reason the schema doesn’t match the actual data in the CSV file, which causes the `FAILFAST` option to be ignored.

Make sure that the `FAILFAST` option works correctly, You need to make the schema matches the actual data in the CSV file.

I reproduce same code in my environment. I got this output with proper schema.

[image]